# "Simple" Spring unit tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, autowired

I'm trying to configure unit testing for an inherited `Spring`-based project. I've tried a few things, but basically I get stuck trying to `@Autowired` stuff into my test cases. Here's my setup:

A controller class that looks like this:

```
@Controller("serverService")
@RequestMapping("/rest/server")
@Api(value = "server")
public class ServerServiceImpl extends AbstractServiceImpl implements ServerService {
    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getTime", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    GatewayResponse<TimeData> getTime() {...}
```

`ServerService` is just an interface that enables interoperation with `GWT`. I'm not too worried about unit testing from `GWT` right now.

`AbstractServiceImpl`'s main purpose is to wrap a `SOAP` based web service that this server is essentially proxying and making mobile friendly. The web service is auto-generated by `Apache CXF`. `AbstractServiceImpl` is (roughly) as follows:

```
public class AbstractServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private WebServices webServices;

    public WebServices getWebServices() {
        return webServices;
    }
```

In my test class I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/applicationContext.xml", "classpath:**/applicationContext-Services.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LoginTest {
    @Autowired
    private ServerServiceImpl svc;

    public LoginTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void validate() {
        assertNotNull(svc);
    }
}
```

I have no interest in trying to create mock calls to my web service with mock JSON and such. I just want to write unit tests that create un-mocked `ServerServiceImpl` with un-mocked `WebServices` objects and make calls to a live server.

My tests are currently failing because `@Autowired` is unable to create `ServerServiceImpl`. I've also tried refactoring my code to use `@Autowired` for the `WebServices` and use pass it to the constructor of `ServerServiceImpl`, but that also fails due to `@Autowired`.

Comment: is the applicationContext.xml in your text classpath or just your live one?

Comment: I only have one applicationContext.xml, so I assume this must be the live one... unless some maven/spring magic is creating another one somehow.

Comment: To unit test these, use constructor injection and a mock library such as Mockito. This lets you avoid Spring entirely and test just the class in isolation without external dependencies.

Comment: Isn't that just going to mock away WebServices, thus preventing me from actually testing the web service underlying all the code in my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was perfectly simple. Spring will throw errors if you specify a non-existent path for an application context, for instance:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:does-not-exist.xml")
```

The above will create a nice easy error message telling you what the problem is, i.e. a file not found exception. On the other hand this code will not:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:**/does-not-exist.xml")
```

So my problem was simply that Spring couldn't find the application context XML. Ultimately I made a copy of the live context, tossed it in `src/test/resources` and updated my `pom.xml`'s `surefire-plugin` and `@ContextConfiguration` as follows:

```
<addtionalClasspathElements>
    <addtionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/test/resources</addtionalClasspathElement>
</addtionalClasspathElements>

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-Services.xml" })
```